# Outlook for Mac 15.9 missing ribbon

Tags: email, ms-office, microsoft, office-365

I have installed a fresh copy of Outlook for Mac v15.9 twice now and after a few days of use the ribbon disappears from all of the windows (main window, email window, etc). When I select View > Ribbon in hopes that it will turn it back on, nothing happens.

How can I get this crazy ribbon back so I am no longer using the menu to send and reply to emails?

Comment: What version of macOS do you have and is this a stand alone Outlook or part of Office? (Wondering here if we have an incompatibility between OS and App.)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem using the 2015 Outlook preview on a Mac.

Quitting (using the shift alt delete equivalent) and restarting the programme gets the ribbon back every time for me.

Answer (score -1):

Confirmed, quitting the application (File --> Quit) and restarting brings back the ribbon.  Annoying.

Comment: You should have added your "Confirmation" as a Comment to the question, and not as an Answer